# Chrome Extension: How to get Extension ID to load local images?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension

I've created an extension that injects/appends a little menu on the body of a gaming forum I participate. It appends a 'menu.html' and a 'menu.js' files I've created.

In the menu I have little cards for each game and each card have the game icon with a fixed size.

**My problem:** How do I load the local game icons from my '/img/icons' extension folder?

I'm able to load the game icons from the internet using the following URL:

```
<a id="imgBattlefield" href="#" target="_blank">    
   <img src="http://files.softicons.com/download/game-icons/battlefield-3-game-icons-by-exhumed/png/128x128/Battlefield%203_4.png"></img>
</a>
```

I then tried to use just the icon path like below, but it's trying to load the image from the website instead of from the extension:

```
<a id="imgBattlefield" href="#" target="_blank">    
   <img src="/img/icons/battlefield.png"></img>
</a>
```

I've tried to use the __ MSG_@@extension_id__ call directly on the SRC path, but I'm pretty sure that's not how it works:

```
<a id="imgBattlefield" href="#" target="_blank">    
   <img src="chrome-extension://__MSG_@@extension_id__/img/icons/battlefield.png"></img>
</a>
```

Over the 'menu.js' file, I've also tried to replace the SRC with javascript like below, but no success either:

```
var imgBattlefield = chrome.extension.getURL("img/icons/battlefield.png");
document.getElementById('imgBattlefield').src = imgBattlefield;
```

**Notes:**

Manifest file already set to use the images:

```
"web_accessible_resources": ["menu.html", "*.jpg", "*.png", "/img/loader.gif"],
```

I'd like to get the extension ID instead of having to set one fixed ID and hard coded it.

What I'm missing?

Comment: You said, `menu.html`, is this like popup.html?

Comment: Have you tried `"./img/icons/battlefield.png"`?

Comment: Hey @RitwickDey, the 'menu.html' file it's not the popup.html. It's a file that is appended to the body of the forum as it would be part of it. I've tried using the path as you mentioned, but it tries to load the image from the forum page like 'www.forumurl.com/img/icons/battlefield.png' and not from extension.

Comment: Oh. I got it.. You have to use `chrome-extension://__MSG_@@extension_id__/img/abc.png'`... Is this not working?

Comment: Try to add, `img/icons/*` in `web_accessible_resources`

Comment: I've tried to use the @@extension, but since is part of the path it does not work as intended, instead, it's part of the SRC text path. I already have '*.jpg' and '*.png' defined on the manifest. Since I'm injecting codes on the page, I guess it's a matter on how to grab the extension ID while injecting code.

Comment: I checked that you've added `*.jpg`... But I'm not sure if it is one level deep. If deep level matters, it should be `**/*.jpg`

Comment: Oh, I see now. I tried over here and I didn't work. It does not seem to be the problem with the manifest, rather solving how to get the extension ID while I'm injecting the code on the forum page (which makes it read the img as if it were part of the forum and not of the extension).

Comment: When you're doing `var imgBattlefield = chrome.extension.getURL("img/icons/battlefield.png");`. What is returning to `imgBattlefield` ? try to log the value

Comment: @RitwickDey It's working now. For some reason the javascript line was not working. Once I switched to jquery using `$('#imgBattlefield').attr("src", imgBattlefield);` the src was replaced correctly. Thanks for all the help :D

Comment: but both code are equivalent

Answer (score 0):

Got it to work! For some reason the javascript line `document.getElementById('imgBattlefield').src = imgBattlefield;` was not working. Once I switched to the equivalent in jquery `$('#imgBattlefield').attr("src", imgBattlefield);` the src path was replaced correctly.